# Nested repeater with Checkbox list using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, repeater

I am trying to do a nested repeater control with check box inside. Basically, what i want is 
categorize the checkboxes like,

```
Group 1
   Item 1
   Item 2

Group 2
   Item 3
   Item 4

Group 3
   Item 5
   Item 6
```

The problem I am facing is, I getting the error :

Error 1 : 'DataRowView' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Error 2 : Name 'DataRowView' is not declared.

ASPX :

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rp_Groups" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rp_Groups_ItemDataBound" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <ul>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk_Group" Text='<%# Eval("category_type") %>' Value='<%# Eval("service_type_category_id") %>' onclick="OnGroupClick" />
                <p class="nested">
                 <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chk_Items" DataValueField="ServiceTypeID" DataTextField="Name"
                 DataSource='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).CreateChildView("FK_esnServiceType_Service_Type_Categorization") %>' ></asp:CheckBoxList>

                </p>
            </ul>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind:

```
Public Sub Fill()  
    Dim dtServiceCategory As DataTable = ServiceTypeModel.GetService_Categories()
    Dim dtServiceType As DataTable = ServiceTypeModel.Search("", True)

    rp_Groups.DataSource = dtServiceCategory
    rp_Groups.DataBind()

    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ds.Tables.Add(dtServiceCategory)
    ds.Tables.Add(dtServiceType)

    Dim relation As New DataRelation("FK_esnServiceType_Service_Type_Categorization", ds.Tables("dtServiceCategory").Columns("service_type_category_id"), ds.Tables("dtServiceType").Columns("CategorizationID"), False)
    ds.Relations.Add(relation)
    relation.Nested = True
End Sub

Protected Sub rp_Groups_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rp_Groups.ItemDataBound
    Dim chklist As CheckBoxList = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("chk_Items"), CheckBoxList)
    If chklist IsNot Nothing Then
        chklist.DataSource = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView).CreateChildView("FK_esnServiceType_Service_Type_Categorization")
        chklist.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check which itemtype is being fired on the `ItemDataBound` event, this may or may not be the problem, as you don't have a header and footer template, however it is still good practice.

```
Protected Sub rp_Groups_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rp_Groups.ItemDataBound
  If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
    Dim chklist As CheckBoxList = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("chk_Items"), CheckBoxList)
    If chklist IsNot Nothing Then
      chklist.DataSource = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView).CreateChildView("FK_esnServiceType_Service_Type_Categorization")
      chklist.DataBind()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I've just noticed that you are adding the relation after you have already binded the repeater's datasource. Try moving the `.databind` after the relation has been added.

**EDIT 2**

OK can you try this. Add the `datatables` to the `dataset` and set the repeaters datasource to: `ds.Tables(0)`

```
Public Sub Fill() 
    Dim ds As New DataSet() 
    Dim dtServiceCategory As DataTable = ServiceTypeModel.GetService_Categories()
    Dim dtServiceType As DataTable = ServiceTypeModel.Search("", True)
    ds.Tables.Add(dtServiceCategory)
    ds.Tables.Add(dtServiceType)
    Dim relation As New DataRelation("FK_esnServiceType_Service_Type_Categorization", ds.Tables("dtServiceCategory").Columns("service_type_category_id"), ds.Tables("dtServiceType").Columns("CategorizationID"), False)
    relation.Nested = True
    ds.Relations.Add(relation)

    rp_Groups.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    rp_Groups.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried both your ideas, and getting error : 'DataRowView' is a type in 'Data' and cannot be used as an expression.   And when I remove datasource of checkboxlist, I am not getting any error !!!

Comment: Yes I did, moved the relation before binding the repeater

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have imported namespace System.Data

Try to add

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
```

to your ASPX file.

As another option you can import namespaces globally, not only in one page:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/simpleman/archive/2006/01/11/80804.aspx

Comment: Now i am getting error : 'DataRowView' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.